# d3.js filtering with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, d3.js

I'm trying to filter some elements with d3 using checkboxes, but I'm not having any luck, and I don't really understand some of the examples I have found (yes, I'm a total noob).

The thing I want to do is display or hide some svgs by comparing their id to the value of the checkboxes.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="value1" class="check" checked>
<label>
    value1
</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="value2" class="check" checked>
<label>
    value2
</label>
...
</form>
```

**D3**

```
var svg = d3.select("div#target")
        .selectAll("svg")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("svg")
        .attr({
            width: width + margin.left + margin.right,
            height: height + margin.top + margin.bottom,
            id: function(d) {
                return d.id;
            }
        })
        .append("g")
        .attr({
            transform: "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")"
        });
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="value2" class="check" onclick="hideSVG('SVGid')" checked>

 <svg id='SVGid'></svg>

 function hideSVG(inValue) {
    if(d3.select("#"+inValue).style("display") == "none") {
       d3.select("#"+inValue).style("display", "block")
    }
    else {
       d3.select("#"+inValue).style("display", "none")
    }
 }
```

The function tests to see if the SVG is being displayed and sets the display to none if it is, or block if it is not. If you're using a different display (like "inline") then just change "block" to "inline".